# Making simple R GUI with tcltk package

Tags: r, function, user-interface, rgui

I'm trying to make very simple GUI for my script. In nutshell problem looks like that :

`dataset` is dataframe, I would like to plot one column as the time and use simple GUI for choosing next/previus column.

`dataset <-data.frame(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), rnorm(10))`

`columnPlot <- function(dataset, i){`

`plot(dataset[, i])`

`}`

how to use `tcltk` for calling `fplot` with different `i`'s ?

Answer (score 8):

Not what you asked for (not `tcltk`related), but I would advise you to have a look at the new [`shiny`](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/) package from RStudio.

Comment: it isn't `tcltk` related, I'm looking for "base" solution

Comment: Here's a link to a blog post I just put up today about making a similar simple GUI. It uses GTK and not tcltk, but check it out. You can use `gWidgets` (the package I used) to do stuff in tcltk also. http://r-norberg.blogspot.com/2012/11/my-first-r-gui.html

Answer (score 3):

Are you particularly attached to the idea of using tcltk? I've been working on something similar using the `gWidgets` package and have had some success. According to it's CRAN site, "gWidgets provides a toolkit-independent API for building interactive GUIs". This package uses tcltk or GTK2 and I've been using the GTK2 portion. Here's a quick example of a GUI with a spinbutton for changing `i`. I also added a little fanciness to your function because you mentioned you would be plotting time series, so I made the x axis Time.

```
data<-data.frame(rnorm(11),rnorm(11),rnorm(11))

i = 1

fplot <- function(i, data = data){
  library(ggplot2)
  TimeStart <- as.Date('1/1/2012', format = '%m/%d/%Y')
  plotdat <- data.frame(Value = data[ ,i], Time = seq(TimeStart,TimeStart + nrow(data) - 1, by = 1))
  myplot <- ggplot(plotdat, aes(x = Time, y = Value))+
    geom_line()
  print(myplot)
}

library(gWidgets)
options(guiToolkit = 'RGtk2')

window <- gwindow ("Time Series Plots", visible = T)
notebook <- gnotebook (cont = window)
group1 <- ggroup(cont = notebook, label = "Choose i", horizontal=F)
ichooser <- gspinbutton(cont = group1, from = 1, to = ncol(data), by = 1, value = i, handler = function(h,...){
  i <<- svalue(h$obj)})
plotbutton <- gbutton('Plot', cont = group1, handler=function(h,...){
  fplot(i, data)})
graphicspane1 <- ggraphics(cont = group1)
```